# Pass values to batch file from Powershell at run time

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a powershell script `P.ps1` which calls batch scripts `B1.bat` and `B2.bat` internally.

`P.ps1` code is as follows:

```
B1.bat
$a= Read-host "Choose 1 or 2:"
B2.bat
Write-host "End of code"
```

`B1.bat` code is :

```
echo "Hello World"
```

`B2.bat` needs input from powershell script.i.e. `$a` has to be sent to `B2.bat`

```
@ECHO OFF
SET var = a 
rem This "a" is coming from "P.ps1"
ECHO We're working with %var%
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use the variable in the PowerShell script like this:

```
B1.bat
$a= Read-host "Choose 1 or 2:"
B2.bat $a
Write-host "End of code"
```

Then in the batch script would do this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET a=%1
rem This "a" is coming from "P.ps1"
ECHO We're working with %a%
```

You use %1 to reference the first variable passed via the command-line, %2 for the second, %3 for the third and so on.

Comment: In batch don't put spaces around the equal sign in a set command. The spaces will become part of the variable name and content.

Answer (score 0):

Since `B1.bat` and `B2.bat` inherit the environment from `P.ps1` you could simply use `$Env:Var=$a` in `P.ps1`

```
PS> gc .\B1.bat
@Echo "Hello World"

PS> gc .\B2.bat
@ECHO OFF
ECHO We're working with %var%

PS> gc .\p.ps1
.\B1.bat
$a = Read-host "Choose 1 or 2 "
$Env:var=$a
.\B2.bat
Write-host "End of code"

PS> .\p.ps1
"Hello World"
Choose 1 or 2 : 1
We're working with 1
End of code
```